# The right way to print strings with timeout in between each characters in C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows

Here is a Code I'm trying to simplify rather than it taking just a line of code to print out two characters. Basically I'm trying to print out series of strings with timeout in between each characters so it would seem to have a typing in keyboard effect.

```
Thread.Sleep(500);
        Console.Write("\nP");Thread.Sleep(60); Console.Write("r"); Thread.Sleep(60);
        Console.Write("o"); Thread.Sleep(60); Console.Write("c"); Thread.Sleep(60);
        Console.Write("e"); Thread.Sleep(60); Console.Write("s"); Thread.Sleep(60);
        Console.Write("s"); Thread.Sleep(60); Console.Write("i"); Thread.Sleep(60);
        Console.Write("n"); Thread.Sleep(60); Console.Write("g"); Thread.Sleep(60);
        Console.Write(" ."); Thread.Sleep(400); Console.Write("."); Thread.Sleep(400);
        Console.Write("."); Thread.Sleep(400);
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why don't you write a method that takes a string a print each character one by one. `Print("Processing...");`

Comment: That is exactly what Eser did and I'm thankful you guys exist! This forum is the best.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void PrintSlowly(string str)
{
    foreach(var c in str)
    {
        Console.Write(c);
        Thread.Sleep(50);
        //Thread.Sleep(c == '.' ? 400 : 50); //if you want to wait longer at .
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

You can call it now

```
PrintSlowly("\nProcessing...");
```

Comment: Actually, Kev wanted to print a sequence of strings, not chars (tough almost all the strings contain only a single character).

Comment: @JohanDonne OP prints 'Processing...'. My guess he/she could also have used char if he/she knew it.

Comment: That was my first impresison as well, but Kev's first string contains 2 chars and further on there is a space combined with a dot,  so I guess he really means strings (anyway he/she can  determine which approach is best suitable).

Comment: Thank you very much for this Eser. It did help me a lot! Saved some space and it's much more neat than my code. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a collection of data like below and loop through it.

```
List<string> datas = new List<string>
        {
            "\nP","r","o" //All data here
        };

        foreach (var data in datas)
        {
            PrintData(data);
        }

private static void PrintData(string data)
    {
        Console.Write(data);
        Thread.Sleep(60);
    }
```

Comment: You can add if condition inside PrintData if your sleep time depends on value

Comment: The first one works better for me. But Thank you very much for your kind opinion sir Vijayanath Viswanathan.